# package fancyhdr: Chapter number on the left and section name on the right

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using the `fancyhdr` package to customize the header of my thesis. I want to have Chapter + chapter number on the left of the page and section name on the left of each page. I'm using the following command, but it didn't quite work

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\leftmark}} 
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}\chaptermark}
```

The document class I'm using is report.

Could anyone help me to achieve what I want?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Are you using `twoside` or `oneside`?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nameref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Chapter \thechapter}
\rhead{\currentname}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Foo}

    \section{Bar}

    \lipsum
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```